Connecting to AFP <3 on 24.10
I'm trying to connect to my G3 iMac running Mac OS 9, from my modern desktop with Ubuntu 24.10, however when I try and connect to my mac, I get the error Unable to connect to the server "G3". The server doesn't support AFP version 3.0 or later.
Is there an easy way for me to allow Ubuntu to connect to older AFP?

You could install the latest PowerPC OS X release compatible with your Mac, which would support AFP version 3 or later. If you have OS 9 applications, you would still be able to run them in classic mode.
